# An example of an non-invertible operator F such that a truncated operator F will be invertible

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, projection

We have:

$X$ - any Banach space

$F : X \to X$ (linear bounded and non-invertible)

$P_n : X \to X$

Where $P_n$ is projector that strongly converges to the identity operator $I$ as $n \to\infty$

Can you help me come up with a linear bounded and non-invertible operator $F$ such that the conditions are satisfied:

$P_nFP_n$ - invertible on $ImP_n$
$\|(P_nFP_n)^{-1} \| < C$ (some constant)
$P_n \to I$ strongly

If you can help at least with idea it also will be great. Thank you very much!
If you think that such example doesn't exist: please can you prove it or help with idea of proving it, thx!

As I understand: F should have some a feature at infinity that does not appear in the finite case. But if I try to come up with this consideration in the operator, I get either an unbounded or nonlinear operator.

I had idea like this:
$X = l2 $ space

$Fx = (x_1f(x),...,x_nf(x),..)$,

where $f(x)=1$ when $x$ has zeros and $f(x)=0$ when $x$ has not zeros. And it partly works: $F$ - non-invertible and $PnFPn$ - invertible (because it always has zeros). But in this case $F$ - is non-linear. Maybe you can help me to improve this example. But I think it is not right way.

[This task is related with projection method. There is defenition. Maybe it will be helpfull](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IC0yx.jpg)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150054/discussion-on-question-by-tortedeline-an-example-of-an-non-invertible-operator-f); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.